# yacc (bison) parse tree unordered print

Tags: parsing, tree, bison, yacc

I have this example of a grammar that one of the symbols can take different values

```
StatementList : Statement RepeatStatementList { $$=insert_statement_list($1, $2); }
                ;

RepeatStatementList : RepeatStatementList SEMICOLON Statement { $$=insert_repeat_statement_list($1, $3); }
        | { $$ = NULL; }
                    ;

Statement : NUMBER { $$=insert_statement(NULL, $1); }
            ;

Statement : ID { $$=insert_statement($1, NULL); }
;
```

I defined the structures and the inserts as below:

```
struct statement_list_
{
    st* s;
    struct rstlist *r;

} stlist;

struct repeat_statement_list_
{
    st* s;
    struct repeat_statement_list_ *next;
} rstlist;


struct statement_
{
    char *id;
    int number;

} st;


stlist* insert_statement_list(rstlist *r, st* s)
{
    stlist* l = (stlist*)malloc(sizeof(stlist));
    l->s = s;
    l->r = r;

    return l;
} 

rstlist* insert_repeat_statement_list(rstlist *next, st *s)
{
    rstlist* l = (rstlist*)malloc(sizeof(rstlist));
    l->s = s;
    l->next = next;

    return l;
}

st* insert_statement(char* id, int n)
{
    st* l = (st*)malloc(sizeof(st));
    l->id = id;
    l->number = n;

    return l;
}
```

The problem i have is if i pass an input like:

```
id1
1
2
3
id2
```

What i get in terms of visited items is:

```
id1
1
id2
3
2
```

What is wrong with my structures?

Bear in mind that this is a sample so missing or misplaced semicolons or brackets can be ignored. :-)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert_repeat_statement_list needs to append the statement to the end of the existing rstlist, rather than prepending it onto the beginning of the list.

insert_statement_list takes an `rstlist *` as its first argument and a `st *` as the second arg, but you're calling it with those argument types reversed.  This should give you a compile error, unless your `%type` declarations (which you don't show) are messed up (and if they are messed up, everything will likely misbehave.)

Comment: yes that's it. Also i removed the RepeatStatementList and added a second option to the StatementList. Simplified